# Ember Data: Is it possible to commit any/all unsaved changes without calling save on a per-model basis?

Tags: ember.js, save, ember-data, commit, autosave

I would like to create routes with forms/input that change several models and then save all changes either as I transition away or with a single action. Ideally, something like this:

```
App.Autosavable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    actions: {
        willTransition: function(transition) {
            //Saving everything.
            console.log("App.Autosavable::willTransition: Saving any dirty records")
            this.store.commit();
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately it seems that committing the store has been replaced with the pattern of explicitly saving each model.

If I have complex actions on my route, does that mean I must keep track of each model that could be changed for each route and save it explicitly?

I'd really like to just save everything that the store has listed internally as an updated attribute for every model.

Comment: :@genkilabs, did you already find a solution for this?

Comment: No luck. I ended up changing my design pattern and adding a debounced autosave based on this work http://gaslight.co/blog/an-autosave-pattern-for-ember-and-ember-data You can find my solution here: https://gist.github.com/Genkilabs/8404456 Hope this helps someone.

Comment: that looks great! However, does it also take care of belongsTo and hasMany fields? I have now a very ugly working version with observers on each belongsTo and hasMany field item like this: `hasMany.@each` which is a bit heavy I think.

Comment: Ya, it works. Lets say you have a Group with Members: ```App.Group = DS.Model.extend(App.AutosavableModel, { members: DS.hasMany('member', {async: true}) }``` then add the mixin to both the model and controllers for Group and Members. Your view will have something like: ```{{#each group.members itemController="member"}}
 <tr>Age: {{view App.NumberField valueBinding="age" min="0" class="key-numeric"}}</tr>
{{/each}}```. The key point is the itemController for the context of the items in the each block.

Comment: @genkilabs does this still work for you? I'm having issues getting anything invoked. :-\